# RLC circuit: change R and C because of constraint in L

Tags: audio, filter, passive-filter

I am trying to build this circuit, but I can only find 47 μH inductors. Is there any way I can change R and C to get an equivalent circuit?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what properties you are willing to give up. e.g. The simplest option of rescaling all impedances will affect the input and output impedances significantly.

Comment: Can I run diesel in my petrol car?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of 470uH inductors for sale on, for example, Ebay https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/281770277470

Have you tried simulating it to see the effect of using inductors 1/10 the the value specified? You would have to use capacitors with 10 times the value, 10uf, to obtain the same frequency response. The inductors have almost negligible resistance compared to the resistors, so provided the substitute parts are similar you would probably not have to change the resistors.

One downside of using components so far removed from the ones specified is that 10uF capacitors are going to be quite a bit bigger, expensive and possibly harder to obtain. Don't forget they will have to be non-polar, electrolytics are no good for this application.